# jQuery Mobile some links stuck on loading

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile and like the title says, for some reason some links get stuck on the loading spinner and do not open the next page.  Here's the code:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Top News</li>
                <?php
                include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
                $html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');
                foreach ($html->find('*.overridable a[class=title]') as $main){
                    echo '<li><a href="news.php?url='.urlencode($main->href).'" data-transition="slidedown">'.$main->plaintext.'</a></li>';
                }
                ?>
                <li data-role="list-divider">Other News</li>
                <?php
                    include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
                    $html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');
                    foreach ($html->find('div[class=river-post yui-u] h2 a[href*=example]') as $ret){
                        echo '<li><a href="othernews.php?url='.urlencode($ret->href).'" data-transition="slidedown">'.$ret->plaintext.'</a></li>';
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

As you can see, I'm sending the clicked URL to the next page and parsing the article.  For some reason, one or two links just get stuck on the loading spinner.  The data of the articles is the same format as the others but it does not open.  BUT when I get rid of jQuery and use plain HTML, everything opens as it should.  The link gets sent to the URL and gets parsed on the next page.  Any ideas why some links get stuck?

Updated errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: YChartsQuoteEmbed is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the answer.  The problem was that the HTML which I was returning on my news.php and othernews.php pages, some of the content was Javascript.  I needed to skip over that Javascript and now the pages load just fine.  The Javascript code that was parsed was interfering with the jQuery Mobile code.